# Why is the alignment of the text not the same as the code? How do I fix it's?

Tags: html, css, css-position, text-align

After eliminating the other codes, this is the code that's left.  There are also other codes that are similar to this one just with different content and I'm suspecting they have the same problem.  But I can't seem to figure out how I can get the alignment right for this code.  I checked for open and close tags and indents but everything seem fine.

I tried checking it on developer tools too but it doesn't  have the attributes I wanted the text to get.

I also tried display block but it doesn’t work either.

**Can you please tell me how to fix this code?**

```
<html>

 <head>
        <title>Webpage Design</title>
        <style>
                     .sc { text-align: center; }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <a class = 'sc' href= 'http://stackexchange.com'>
        THE TEXT THAT WON'T ALIGN</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of alignment are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jackson5 .sc { text-align: center;}

Comment: Please don't change the question such that it no longer contains the problem code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: block` in your style `sc` class, see the codes below:

```
<html>
     <head>
            <title>Webpage Design</title>
            <style>
                 .sc { text-align: center; display: block;}
            </style>
      </head>
      <body>
            <a class = 'sc' href= 'the link to the website'>
            THE TEXT THAT WON'T ALIGN</a>
      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot align an Anchor tag, If you want to align use `display: block` or add `div` or `p` tag in front of it and then align that `div` or 'p`.

```
<html>
 <head>
        <title>Webpage Design</title>
        <style>
             .sc { text-align: center;}
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<p>
Some content here <br />
        <div class= 'sc'><a href= 'the link to the website'>
        THE TEXT THAT WON'T ALIGN</a></div><br />
Some content here <br />
  </body>
</html>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rxm1fkh0/1/)

Comment: Did you try the demo provided?

Comment: Did you pressed the run button after going to that link?

Comment: The link work but when I tried it on my own code it doesn't

Comment: For that you have to provide the **real code** in the question not virtual.

Answer (score 0):

In this context if you make the `<a>` a block element it will center as example

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Webpage Design</title>
  <style>
    .sc {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a class='sc' href='the link to the website'>THE TEXT THAT WON'T ALIGN</a>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Webpage Design</title>
    <style>
      .sc { display: block; 
            text-align: center; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class= 'sc' href='the link to the website'>THE TEXT THAT WON'T ALIGN</a>
  </body>
</html >
```